# Try Catch block where does the code stop if you have multiple things happening in the try block?

Tags: php, try-catch

In the following over simplified scenario, I'm wondering if firstFunction() fails, will secondFunction() still run but then show the error, or will it break out of the try block when firstFunction fails?

```
try {
    firstFunction();
    secondfunction();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e... 
}
```

Comment: It will stop where the error is. Once it hits an error, it stops and immediately jumps to the catch block.

Comment: Thank you, thats what I thought, but I have some code that is not working like that. I'm not sure why it's still running that second part when the first part fails. But I'll keep digging.

Comment: If it's a warning, it won't be caught as an exception and will keep on going.

Comment: The first part is a query to add a record to a mysql database, it should fail if the unique identifier already exists, in that case I don't want to do the second part. Which was working on my localhost, but for some reason on the live server it does the second part anyway.  I'm getting a mysqli_sql_exception if I remove the try catch. So I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Can you confirm that the exception is actually coming from the first function, and not the second one?

Comment: I would look at the php versions on the two servers - in the past php was much less inclined to throw when there is an error, but rather leave it to the coder to check for success.

Comment: Chris , yes I can confirm the first one is throwing the error. Good thought though.